# Unresponsive Apple Magic Keyboard

Tags: imac

My 10 year-old Apple Magic keyboard is not working. No green light display and attempting to connect to keyboard #1. I have restarted my computer 3 times, put in recently purchased batteries with no response from my keyboard. Any suggestions before I purchase a new keyboard?

Comment: Purchase a new keyboard.

Comment: Smashing it on the desk to check for a loose connection might be in order at that stage.

Comment: I replaced the keyboard.